# TableHeaderView not changing after reassigning view

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I have two separate views and I want to use it as a `tableHeaderView` (for plain and edit mode accordingly).

When `setEditing` called for the first time, it sets `tableHeaderView` to the first view. After that `tableHeaderView` is not changing at all, even if you'll set it to nil, it keep showing first assigned view. I tried `reloadData` before and after assignment, but it doesn't help.

```
class EditVC: UITableViewController {
    lazy var viewTableHeaderView:ViewTableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewTableHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as ViewTableHeaderView
    lazy var editTableHeaderView:EditTableHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("EditTableHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as EditTableHeaderView

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    if editing{
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.editTableHeaderView
    }else{
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.viewTableHeaderView
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have not changed the editing mode at all because you have not called super. Add this to the beginning of the method:

```
 super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
```